# BugSplat's SendPdbs.exe fails to upload symbols

Tags: debug-symbols

About a week ago, I found that my SendPdbs.exe doesn't work anymore. It fails to send my application's symbols to BugSplat. The only way I can send my symbols to BugSplat now is by using the "Create New Symbol Store" function on BugSplat's website. This is very inconvenient, because that means I cannot upload symbols automatically. I have to do it manually now.

Has anyone ever had this kind of problems before?

Below is the command I use to send my application's symbols to BugSplat:

```
C:\>Sendpdbs.exe /a AppName /v "v2.0.0.0" /u username /p password /d "myDir" /f "test.dll" /b database_name
SendPdbs: Sendpdbs.exe /a AppName /v v2.0.0.0 /u username /p password /d "myDir" /f test.dll /b database_name
   Initializing...
Creating zip file...
    adding myDir\test.dll SUCCESS
sending zipped symbols...

Connecting to secure FTP server

Symbol upload connection established
Symbol upload remote staging complete
Symbol upload successful!
```

Although SendPdbs.exe tells me that I have successfully uploaded my symbols, I still cannot find them on https://www.bugsplatsoftware.com/symbols/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that you are having this issue!  I work for Bugsplat support and it appears that the issue affecting your account was with our back-end.  Our engineers made a change yesterday to address this problem.  Please run sendpdbs again and let me know how it goes.

If you are still having issues, we would be more than happy to help you!  Send us an email at support@bugsplatsoftware.com.

Thanks!

-Bobby

Bugsplat Support